# Why Log4j2 doesn't write logs to a file?

Tags: java, log4j2

This is my configuration `log4j2.xml` with `path to file` - `src/com/tarasiuk/task_01/log/dataLogger.log`:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">

    <Properties>
        <Property name="FORMAT_MESSAGE">
            %d{YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%t] Level:%-7p Class:%c{1}:%-5L - %msg%n
        </Property>

        <Property name="LOG_FILE">
            src/com/tarasiuk/task_01/log/dataLogger.log
        </Property>
    </Properties>

    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="${FORMAT_MESSAGE}" />
        </Console>

        <File name="File" fileName="${LOG_FILE}" append="false">
            <PatternLayout pattern="${FORMAT_MESSAGE}" />
        </File>
    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="org.apache.logging.log4j.test2" level="debug" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="File" />
        </Logger>

        <Root level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

**Structure of my project:**
[image]

What I do:

1. change `path` to log file from `src/com/tarasiuk/task_01/log/dataLogger.log` to `com/tarasiuk/task_01/log/dataLogger.log` - no result.
2. change `level` in `<Logger>` from `debug` to `info` - no result.

Logs are output to the console - that ok. But why `Log4j2` doesn't write logs `to a file`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with below appender.

May be in your case it is not able to get path from property, so i had provided only name.
So automatically it will create file on same path as your application is.

```
<Appenders>
    <File name="dataLogger" fileName="dataLogger.log" append="false">
       <PatternLayout pattern="%level - %m%n"/>
    </File>
    <Console name="STDOUT" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
      <PatternLayout pattern="%level - %m%n"/>
    </Console>
  </Appenders>
```

This will help you.

Comment: @n199a now just try with static path. Just copy absolute path task01/log/dataLogger.log an put in filename field. If this works then try with property.

Comment: log4j2.xml located in /task_01/src/log4j2.xml and file 'dataLogger.log' was successfully created in /task_01/src/dataLogger.log. But I need the file 'dataLogger.log' to be created in /src/com/tarasiuk/task_01/log/dataLogger.log on my Ubuntu.

Comment: absolute path `/home/n199a/Documents/java/workspace/2_epam_industrial_programming_in_java/task_01/src/com/tarasiuk/task_01/log/dataLogger.log` - it worked. But need in `/src/com/tarasiuk/task_01/log/dataLogger.log`

Comment: Now try with ../src/com/tasiuk

Comment: it's magic, just rigth click on file `dataLogger.log` in `IDEA -> copy -> Path from content root` and puste in `log4j2.xml`. Result - `src/com/tarasiuk/task_01/log/dataLogger.log`. strangely, when I typed the path with my hands - it didn't work. Copied it - it worked.
It worked! Thank you

Comment: Great, keep it up ..!! 

Answer (score 0):

I had this error when using relative path on a linux server. I was starting my program using a `sh` script.

Unlike Windows, that sets the current directory based on where the launching script is placed, Linux sets the current directory as the user home directory (unless specified otherwise).

You can specify otherwise by using the `cd` command and move to the directory where the `sh` script is launched

So in my case, log file was created, but in the wrong location (i.e inside the home of the user).
If you are having the same problem just prepend a `cd` command to your `sh` script.